# How to retrieve data from a GitHub project board?

Tags: python, github, github-api

For a work, I have to retrieves some data from a project board on GitHub (the start and end dates of iterations).

I have read a lot of things about GitHub API (REST and GRAPHQL) and I tried many way to retrieve even the most basic data, but at this point all my attempts still unsucessfull.

In fact, my goal is to retrieve the start and end dates of those 'iterations' in order to create a reminder.

- In my code, I have replaced OWNER and REPO with the correct ones

```
access_token = 'MY_TOKEN'
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}'}

owner = 'OWNER'
repo = 'REPO'

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/projects'

headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
projects_data = response.json()

print(projects_data)

for project in projects_data:
    project_id = project['id']
    project_name = project['name']
    print(f"Project: {project_name}, ID: {project_id}")
```

- I changed my code and now it's look like this :

```
query = """
query {
  organization(login: "ORG_NAME") {
    projects(first: 5) {
      nodes {
        name
        body
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}'}

org = 'ORG_NAME'

url = f'https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG_NAME/projects'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
projects_data = response.json()

for project in projects_data:
    project_name = project['name']
    print(f"Project Name: {project_name}")
```

I defined the token before and I don't put it here, and I replaced the name of the organisation by ORG_NAME

`print(response.json())` return me this : []

I checked, the org have 5 projects and when I created my token, I checked : all of the 'repo' boxes, the 'read:org', and the 'read:project' (the only one in 'project' category)

Comment: Just making sure. Token is also your real token and not just 'MY_TOKEN', right? Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, 'MY_TOKEN' isn't the real one

Comment: I got this : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adrien/errbot-reminder/errbot-reminder.py", line 28, in <module>
    project_id = project['id']
                 ~~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: And for the `print(projects_data)` I got this : {'message': 'Bad credentials', 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/rest'}

Comment: First of all, you've got the headers line twice :P Second, try changing `token` to `Bearer` and see if that changes anything

Comment: There is no changes

Comment: I see you updated the code once again. Try to see if it works with `Bearer` now. `token` will most likely not work. My guess right now would be that the token wasn't generated correctly

Comment: I just tried it but the result is the same. I don't have any error, just the first print which return me []